# Listas en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy creando una función que consiste en encontrar el nombre un país en una lista con nombres limitados, si el nombre está en la lista la función retornará el index de este, sino mostrará un mensaje. La función va así:

```
paises=['Portugal', 'Suiza', 'Alemania', 'Francia', 'Belgica', 'Chile']
    def error_index(pais):
        if pais != str:
            print('Introduce el nombre del país entre comillas dobles ("") o simples ('').\nNo se aceptan caracteres difrente a letras.')
        else:
            if pais in paises:
                indice = paises.index(pais)
                return indice
            else:
                print('pais no encontrado')
```

Lo que quiero lograr es que cuando en el parámetro no se coloque un `string` como tal, sino un simple nombre sin comillas aparezca el mensaje

> Introduce el nombre del país entre comillas dobles ("") o simples
>   (''). No se aceptan caracteres diferente a letras.

En lugar del siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    error_index(francia)
NameError: name 'francia' is not defined
```

Pensé que colocando la parte de `if pais != str:` lo lograría, pero al parecer también lo toma como `string`. ¿Cómo podría solucionar esto?

También me gustaría saber de que forma hacer que pueda encontrar coincidencia entre el argumento dado a la función y los nombres de la lista sin distinguir entre mayúsculas y minúsculas

Comment: ¿Necesariamente el usuario tiene que entrar los datos entre comillas?. La instrucción `input` de python 3 siempre devuelve el valor introducido por teclado como un string, aunque sean números.

Comment: Si el usuario ingresa la cadena con comillas lo que se ingresa es la cadena `'"Portugal"'` y por tanto esa debe ser la clave del diccionario, no `'Portugal'`. Para que tu código funcione basta con que el usuario ingrese la cadena sin comillas como comenta aeportugal.

Answer (score 1):

No se puede ver la instrucción de entrada del usuario, pero si da un error de `Traceback (most recent call last)` es porque probablemente estes usando un

```
pais = eval(input("texto..."))
```

La función `input()` devuelve un string siempre, así que si estás trabajando con strings, no es necesario evaluarlos.

Otra cosa. Sabemos que no todas las funciones tienen que devolver datos; pero si una variable está esperando un valor de una función, entonces la función en cuestión SIEMPRE tiene que devolver algo, aunque sea un `False`, o un `-1` si no le fue posible hallar un resultado válido. Python quizás no se queje porque no le estas devolviendo un valor a la variable, pero lo va a reemplazar con `None` o alguna basura. Otros lenguajes más estrictos no te lo van a dejar pasar.

El código se podría reescribir así

```
paises=['Portugal', 'Suiza', 'Alemania', 'Francia', 'Belgica', 'Chile']

def buscar_pais(pais):
    if pais in paises:
        indice = paises.index(pais)
    else:
        print('pais no encontrado')
        indice = False
    return indice

# Lineas para pruebas
pais = input("Introduce un pais: ")
result = buscar_pais(pais)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Para saber el tipo de dato que se tiene puedes utilizar **type()**, pero en este caso no es necesario sabiendo que probablemente uses **input()** para obtener datos por pantalla y seran de tipo **str** (dejo validacion abajo aunque no es muy necesaria para el caso que uses **input()**) y para la busqueda del elemento dentro del arreglo de "paises" puedes pasar todo al minuscula dentro del arreglo con **lower()** e iterar en cada uno de los elementos de el arreglo original y asi filtrar el parametro que entra en la funcion. salu2 :)

```
paises=['Portugal', 'Suiza', 'Alemania', 'Francia', 'Belgica', 'Chile']

def error_index(pais):
    if type(pais) != str: # usar type para comparar si el dato ingresado es de tipo string
        print('Introduce el nombre del país entre comillas dobles ("") o simples ('').\nNo se aceptan caracteres difrente a letras.')
    else:
        paisesEnMinuscula = [x.lower() for x in paises] #iterar arreglo pasando a minucula cada uno de sus elementos
        print(paisesEnMinuscula)
        if pais in paisesEnMinuscula:
            indice = paisesEnMinuscula.index(pais)
            print ("El indice del pais encontrado es: "+str(indice))
        else:
            print('pais no encontrado')

paisInput = input("Ingresa un pais: ")

pais = paisInput.lower().strip() # Todo a minuscula y sin espacios

error_index(pais)
```